# Check dynamic route express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have some routes for example `/login/:provider/:id` and when the request is executed it gets something like `/login/provider1/123`. Everything fine so far but the problem arise when I want to have certain routes without authentication for my middleware.

So far I have tried like this:

```
public static getString(value: String): String {
        let values = value.split('/');
        if (values.length <= 2) return value;
        return values.slice(0, values.length - 1).reduce(((previousValue, currentValue) => {
            return previousValue + "/" + currentValue;
        }));
    }
```

but it is not very generic and does not catch all the cases.

What it should match the original route is:

`/login/anything/anything`

So I take this route: `/login/:provider/:id` that has 3 segments:
[login, provider, id] so anything that starts from /login and has same number of segments should match.

and it should not match anything without same length of segments.

My question is: Is there any specific way of getting the original route without looping after the request made? Is what I am asking possible through regexp?

Comment: Your express version?

Comment: 4.16.0 is my express version

Comment: Can you give us some example what should match with the route and what shouldn't

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: I tried to answer your question but I am still not sure if I understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need custom validators for your route.

You can create routers.

```
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.param(function(param, validator) {
    return function(req, res, next, val) {
        // You have full access to req. So you can get anything from it.
        if (validator(val)) {
            next(); //validator success no need for authorization.
        } else {
            if (req.headers.Authentication) {
                next() //Validator failed but we have token in header and it is valid.
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(403); //Validator failed and token does not exists.
            }
        }
    }
});


router.param('provider', function(candidate) {
    return candidate === 'myprovider' //Provider condition that will bypass authorization.
});

router.get('/login/:provider/:id', function (req, res) { //register the route
  res.send('OK');
});

app.use(router);
```

Edit 2 (Another try):

```
app.all('/:id/:name', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  next();
});
```

This will match only this type of routes. And it will work before them so you have access to every param you need.

Comment: yes but in this case I will have to create custom validators for every route. However I was thinking more like a generic answer

Comment: Ok now I understood your question. You want to use `.use` and validate before the actual routes?

Comment: Great question, trying to find a solution now.

Comment: thanks a lot. Thank you especially for your answer but just FYI the router.param has been deprecated the one with validator()

Comment: Thank you for it, just learned something. I think I found a solution. Editing the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181902/discussion-between-kostas-drak-and-ahmet-can-guven).

Answer (score 0):

The only dirty solution that I came up with is this:

```
public static doesNotRequireAuth(value: String): boolean {
        let delimiter = "/";
        let segments = value.split(delimiter);
        let conditionMet = false;
        getNoAuthRoutes().forEach((item) => {
            let itemSegments = item.split(delimiter);
            if (segments[1] === itemSegments[1] && segments.length === itemSegments.length) {
                conditionMet = true;
                return;
            }
        });
        return conditionMet;
    }
```

where the `getNoAuthRoutes()` is a `Set<String>`.

Hope it helps someone!!!